# UK Ancestry Visa, Dependents application

Tags: uk-visa

I have applied for the 'UK Ancestry Visa' and it has been granted. However, for my husband we have had a complete nightmare. We have used an agent and the visa category and type used are :non points-based working visa, Dependent for more than 6 months. 
Our agent assures us this is the correct visa and type, however the Immigration center located in Amman states that it is not and keeps insisting that he withdraw his application and resubmit under the same as me 'UK Ancestry Visa'.
My husband does not have have UK Ancestral ties and this has now turned into a complete nightmare. UK Immigration have now refunded money back into the bank account and no-one seems to want to help or listen to us. We have escalated this issue twice and it has been completely useless, being told to wait 15 days at  time. Today I have started to write complaints.
Are you able to clarify that we have applied for the right visa and type, as I have seen a link here that indicates we have.
This is now taking so long that my Vignette is due to expire in 10 days and I have no idea how to extend it, can you advise on how to do this too since I am having no luck finding this information on the websites.

Thanks from Hails

Answer (score 3):

The correct visa type for your husband is:

> Work Visa type : Non points based working visas Visa sub-type : Dependant more than 6 months.

I can confirm the visa type, as I am on the same one.

Unfortunately I don't know how you could extend your Vignette. My guess would be that you can't extend it. You need to either travel to the UK for 10 days to get your BRP and then return, or re-apply for your Visa and pay the associated costs again.

Comment: [You can apply for a "Transfer of Conditions"](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/transferring-a-visa-to-a-new-passport-ecb17/transferring-a-visa-ecb17#ecb173-replacing-a-30-day-short-validity-travel-vignette) if you don't travel in the vignette validity period. This will cost you around 200 USD. You can check the fee for your country [here](https://visa-fees.homeoffice.gov.uk/). It's listed under "other fees".